# how to restart in java japplet?

Tags: game-loop

how to restart a game? problem with my code is that when it restarts it double the enemy. so there are 10 enemies and lets say player dies than user restart and now there are 20 enemies and so on.....

in start method i am create 10 enemies and storing in arraylist

```
public void start()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
    enemyObject = new Enemy(10*i,10);
    enemyStore.add(enemyObject);    //store in array
   }
}
```

in here i am making enemy move, collision etc and if enemy is dead than i am remooving it from arraylist

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < enemyStore.size(); i++){       
        enemyObject = (Enemy)enemyStore.get(i);
            if(!enemyObject.getDead()){               //if enemy is not died
                //make enemy move, collision etc... here
                                ....
            }
        else{           //remove enemy and create another one
            enemyStore.remove(i);
            enemyObject = new Enemy(10*i, 10); //create enemy
            enemyStore.add(enemyObject);                                               //store in array
        }
    }
}
```

in paint method paint enemy

```
public class Display extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
super.paintComponent(g);

for(int i = 0; i < enemyStore.size(); i++){      //PAINT ENEMY
    enemyObject = (Enemy)enemyStore.get(i);
    enemyObject.paint(g);
        }
   }
}
```

in there if player dies than remove all enemies in arraylist and restart

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
if(playerObject.getDead()){
    if(e.getX() > bx && e.getX() < bx + bw) {
        if(e.getY() > by && e.getY() < by + bh){
            for(int i = 0; i < enemyStore2.size(); i++){
                enemyStore2.remove(i);  
            }       
            start();
         }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: I think this question is actually a question about how to fix your code. I'm voting to close as too localized.

Comment: @Byte56 then it is a question for SO...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Nope, they don't do questions that are too localized either. It is more SO oriented than gamedev oriented however. So that would be the best place for them to make the decision.

Answer (score 2):

if you remove an object at index `i` then all subsequent objects are shifted; in your loops you always skip over the next object (you could in your actionperformed function just use `enemyStore.set(i,enemyObject )` instead of removing and re-adding

in your last code block you are clearing `enemyStore2` and not `enemyStore` (note the 2 at the end

one last note: ArrayList has a clear function which is more efficient than looping and removing and actually works properly